# JPlayer not playing on firefox with mp3 format

Tags: jquery

I have tried almost all method to get play mp3 audio on firefox but gets fail but it works fine on chrome, safari.I have this code:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "audio/45-4.mp3"
        // mp3: "http://sound26.mp3pk.com/indian/ladiesvsricky/ladiesvsrickybahl01(www.songs.pk).mp3"
      })
    },
    swfPath: "http://www.worldhiphopbeats.com/js/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode:"window"
  });
```

If anyone have any knowledge please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: jPlayer should fall back to Flash on Firefox. So is the swfPath correct? Do you see any error message on the console?

Comment: there is no error message in the console.

Comment: I also have the same problem, i see the swf being clearly downloaded under flash tab. And i have installed flash 11 also. Any guesses why jplayer not playing mp3 files in firefox.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you have flash updated/installed on the browser you are using?

Comment: I'm hitting this same issue as of 6/4/2012. I know it's Firefox, because the Flash option on Chrome and IE works fine, but doesn't work on Firefox 12.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was using jQuery.noConflict(true) and not set the noConflict parameter to jPlayer, which is needed for the callbacks from flash to work.

Comment: Can you explain this further? What do you mean "set the noConflict paarameter to jPlayer"?

Comment: e.g. if you have: "my_jquery = JQuery.noConflict(true)", you should pass "noConflict: my_jquery" to jplayer. 

See the jplayer docs here: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-noConflict